# Transfer data between Activities with bundle

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle

I am trying to transfer some data between two activities in android. I need to transfer an Integer value and a list. When I try and retrieve my values in the second activities they are null values. I'm not sure whether it should be in the `onCreate()` method

This is the code to send the data.

```java
public void Start(View view) {
        Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("topics", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) topicsList);
        bundle.putInt("num_players", num_players);
        startActivity(goToNextActivity);

    }
```

This is the code to retrieve the data.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        num_player = extras.getInt("num_players");
        topics_list = extras.getIntegerArrayList("topics");
    }
```

I'm getting a NullPointerException

```
[ERROR] java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

What is the correct way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: you did not put the `bundle` into the intent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forgot to put your bundle into your intent

`goToNextActivity.putExtra("bunlde",bundle)`

or you can do it without a bundle ,just put your data into intent

Answer (score 0):

correct code:

Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
 goToNextActivity .putParcelableArrayList("topics", (ArrayList) topicsList);
        goToNextActivity .putInt("num_players", num_players);
        startActivity(goToNextActivity);